# Magento 2.3 - Newb question - custom test beside the Place Order Button

Tags: magento2.3

I would like to place custom bold text beside the place order button in the checkout payment page. I am new to the Magento framework and I want to make sure to make the change the proper way. I assume editing the core template is not the way, so is there a way to override the template with a custom template? or some sort of hook to insert before or after the Place Order button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="order-comment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">VENDOR_EXTENSION/js/view/comment</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutcomment</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create comment.js

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent'
    ],
    function (ko, $, Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'VENDOR_EXTENSION/checkout/comment'
            }
        });
    }

);
```

In comment.html

```
<form data-role="order-comments" method="post">
    <label><strong>PLACE TEXT HERE</strong></label>
    <textarea class="input-text" name="order_comment" type="text"></textarea>
</form>
```

Create a column in qoute and sales_order column In observer save like this.

```
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
    $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
    $order->setOrderComment( $quote->getOrderComment() );
```

Thanks

Comment: So this works on the review and payments page?